# page.aspx and code behind (page.aspx.vb) relations problems

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I’m working in a web project and I decide to turn in MVC 4 from ASP.NET.
After many issues which I face it, I’m in a position to handle the events raised from the program.
In my previous environment ASPX.NET I was double clicked on a `<asp:Button.../>` control and automatically in the code behind I see the related procedure.
And of course every time I hit the button the program goes to this procedure, and the related event `click`.
Now in MVC 4 I following the same process, but when I’m trying to hit the button the program never goes to the procedure.
Another example is, when I have a Label control and I want to make it visible or Hidden then I use the

`labelId.style.add(“Visibility”,”Hidden”)` or “Visible”.

And another one is:

```
ValidationSummary.ValidationGroup
```

Now in MVC happen the same but before I use the controller. 
(The reason to use the controller is that I want to go to the `asp:button` on_click procedure since the program refuse to go through the event.)
After the controller process the Label control is evaluated but it is completely empty, and with an empty control we can’t do anything.
The same happen in `ValidationSummary` is empty and then it threw an error
 **What I have done until now**
When I use the inheritance `web.UI.Page` the program throws me this error:

```
The view at '~ / Views / Home / Index.aspx' must derive from ViewPage
```

So I change the inheritance to `ViewPage`
And I use the following Javescript to call the controller:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function logSubmit() {
    var url = 'loginSubmit';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
    });
}
</script>
```

And from controller I use these instructions in the function:

```
   Public Function loginSubmit() As JsonResult
      Dim routes As New RouteCollection With {.RouteExistingFiles = True}
      Return Json(New With {Key Attributes.logSubmit.LoginButton_Click}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
   End Function
```

When that happen not any control works from my `page.aspx`

Is there someone to assist me on this issue?

Comment: MVC and Webforms have different concepts regarding controls. In Webforms you're using `<asp:Button ...>` control & handle form validation with `<asp:ValidationSummary ...>`, but in MVC you're using `BeginForm` with `FormMethod.Post` using `<input type="submit" />` & apply viewmodel for validation with `@Html.ValidationSummary()` helper. Of course you can't simply replace `System.Web.UI.Page` with `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage` in existing ASPX webforms page.

Comment: If I leave the `System.Web.UI.Page` of course I get an error and I know that I have to change it. What else I can do for this change. In `ValidationSummary` I use I do some additional issues as well that is the reason Ii use this manner `webforms`. Please be more specific about the `BeginForm` and the `FormMethodePost`

Comment: I'm afraid you can't take the original WebForms based application and turn it into an MVC application with some small code adjustment (or, at least, this is something I would not try for any non-trivial application). Those two development paradigms are quite different from each other.

Comment: Yes you have right to that. I'm face it, with many problems. Now I'm trying to use `razorpage` with `LayoutPage`. Wish me luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said on the comments Asp.net web forms and Asp.Net MVC are a totally different concept. I know you know that. Asp.net Web forms work on code behind concept whereas Asp.Net MVC has route-based URLs means URLs are divided into controllers and actions and moreover it is based on controller not on physical file. In web forms, there are server controls but  Asp.Net MVC follow customizable syntax (Razor as default). And again as said on comments you cannot change System.Web.UI.Page with System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage in existing ASPX web forms page. So you need to have your views using a razor syntax. From your question what I can suggest is like below.

```
    // View.    
@ModelType ViewModel   //Model you want to bind to the view.
     @Using Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", New With {.ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl}, FormMethod.Post) // we pass action name as first parameter and controller name as third parameter.
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @<text>
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(True, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Email, New With {.class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Email, New With {.class = "form-control"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Email, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Password, New With {.class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(Function(m) m.Password, New With {.class = "form-control"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Password, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </text>
            End Using
```

And in the controller.

```
    Public Class AccountController
        Inherits Controller
        <HttpPost>
        <AllowAnonymous>
        <ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
        Public Async Function Login(model As LoginViewModel, returnUrl As String) As Task(Of ActionResult)
            If Not ModelState.IsValid Then
                Return View(model)
            End If
// Your code logic
            Dim result = Await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout := False)
            Select Case result
                Case SignInStatus.Success
                    Return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl)
                Case SignInStatus.LockedOut
                    Return View("Lockout")
                Case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification
                    Return RedirectToAction("SendCode", New With {
                        returnUrl,
                        model.RememberMe
                    })
                Case Else
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.") // Because of this we can show the validation summary on view using  @Html.ValidationSummary
                    Return View(model)
            End Select
        End Function
    End Class
```

And the model is.

```
//In your case model class is different.
Public Class LoginViewModel
    <Required>
    <Display(Name:="Email")>
    <EmailAddress>
    Public Property Email As String

    <Required>
    <DataType(DataType.Password)>
    <Display(Name:="Password")>
    Public Property Password As String

End Class
```

I just described the way to handle your issue to my understanding from your question.

Comment: Yes you have understanding very well my question. The issue for me is not (so much) only to handle the login view page. But to handle the login data after the `loginButton_Click`. Really it is very difficult and now I need to start all over from scratch. With less knowledge about MVC. Thanks any way

Comment: @LefterisGkinis if my answer is helpful to you then could you please accept my answer? Or do you need any more explanation?

Comment: that instruction `ViewBag.ReturnUrl` threw me an error of `ReturnUrl not defined` why is that? And one more The Validation strings... where are they ?  don't we use them ?

Comment: Is it throwing the error on runtime or before compiling?

Comment: Before of runtime

Comment: @LefterisGkinisI cannot tell what exactly might have happened. I can tell that if you configure as I explained you will able to make it work. I think you might have already done it. Sorry for late response.